# com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Literal and com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ResourceFactory not present in 9.2.3 jar or other recent jars?

Tags: sparql, apache-jena, arq

I added the jena arq 2.9.3 jar file to my code to be able to run sparql queries for DBpedia but it says that the literal and resource factory classes are not present. Do I need to add another version of the jar file or do I need to make changes to package names or import class names to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you use Maven? Otherwise you have to add **all *.jar files** from Jena distribution to the classpath. And of course you have to import the packages, but any IDE should support you in doing that

Comment: By the way, latest Jena version is `3.2.0` . What's the reason for using the `2.x` API?